# Haven't Upgraded GCP Free tier account. Still receiving Invoice in Mail

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created a free tier account in GCP for learning purpose based on the assurance "New customers also get $300 in free credits to fully explore and conduct an assessment of Google Cloud Platform. You won’t be charged until you choose to upgrade."

I haven't upgraded my GCP to a paid account, But I have been receiving hefty invoices in Mail. Could anyone help me in this regard. I could also not find a email or a phone support, so that I can enquire regarding this

Comment: What resources are you using? You can also monitor what you're spending on in billing.

Comment: @AnishSinha, I have created a compute engine, sql and a bucket. The problem is that it's a free account and I haven't upgraded.

Comment: Just check the billing tab on the console and check how many more free credits you have

Comment: Please do not use words like **hefty**. People interpret these types of adjectives differently. Edit your question and clearly state facts. Include details after you check your Payments account and Billing account.

Answer (score 1):

If you received an unexpected invoice for Google Cloud, you can use the [Unknown Google Cloud Charge Inquiry](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_unknown_charges) as descibed in the document [Unrecognized Google Cloud or Google Maps Platform charges](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/resolve-issues#unrecognized-charges).

Answer (score 1):

You have several options for cleaning up your project that allow you to avoid unwanted charges.

- [Disable your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/cleaning-up#disabling_your_application)

Retain your project name, application data, and other project resources while preventing charges from traffic to your web service.

- [Disable billing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/cleaning-up#disabling_billing)

Retain your project name and application data while preventing charges for any resources associated with your project.

- [Delete your project](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/cleaning-up#deleting_your_project)

Delete your project name, application data, and all other project resources.

To delete a project, use the `gcloud projects delete` command:

```
gcloud projects delete PROJECT_ID
```